# Setting values in pandas dataframe dependent on in-row values and column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have an (n-1)xn matrix built as a Pandas dataframe.  It looks something like this:

```
IDX | team       | Louisville | Vanderbilt | Miami | ... | Toledo | Duke |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Louisville |     14     |     0      |   0   | ... |    0   |   0  |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Vanderbilt |      0           14     |   0   | ... |    0   |   0  |
```

And onward.  The diagonal of the matrix is filled with how many games the team has played (Louisville has had 14 games total).  The rest of the values in the dataframe are 0's.

There is also another dataframe in the notebook that is called "games" with column headers of:

```
games = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['team1','team2','team1points','team2points']
```

It is filled with game data, one row per game.  What I am trying to do is build opponent lists for each team and then in the matrix, where the row team has played the column team, simply place a negative one.  Here's the code I'm trying to do it with:

```
def fillnegones(row):
    teamsgames = games[(games['team1'] == row[0]) | (games['team2'] == row[0])]
    opponents = list(teamsgames[teamsgames['team1'] != row[0]]['team1'])
    opponents.extend(list(teamsgames[teamsgames['team2'] != row[0]]['team2']))
    for team in opponents:
        row[team] = (-1)
matrix = matrix.apply(fillnegones, axis=1)
```

I have tried this with row[0] and row['team'] to no avail.  I believe my problem is in the self-referencing of the rows, but I'm not sure.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pivot_table with parameters team1 for rows, team2 for columns, team1 for group operation, count for function. You will get a similar table as matrix.